# Is it appropriate to ask how to pronounce common filenames?

Tags: discussion

I'm curious on how to pronounce a specific Linux file when speaking out loud.  Is that an appropriate question to ask? Or too subjective?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess you could ask what the accepted pronunciation is for a given command, since any common command will probably have one. Less well known projects that have unclear pronunciations probably address it on their website.

There have already been a couple of such questions which was quite well received:

- [Pronunciation for /usr directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/103347/22222)
- [Why do Unix-heads say "minus"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2212/22222)

Comment: Time to ask about how to pronounce `fsck`.

Comment: I would dare you to ask for a specific user's `bjobs`

Comment: Postgresql even has an audio recording in their press faq: http://www.postgresql.org/about/press/faq/ Last question on the page. I think it's completely appropriate.